# Searching for element in Skip List

Tags: java, list, skip-lists

I'm having some difficulty coding up a way to find an element in a Skip List.

I'm trying to implement it so that, if we're searching for an element and that element doesn't exist in the List, then return the next largest value; this would make it ideal for insertion.
However, if the element *is* located, then return that element.

I use this for my `remove(T key)` method; if we find the element, then remove it. If it isn't in the list, `throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()`.

While my current implementation works okay for insertion, I've come to find out that it doesn't work at finding an existing element--instead, it will get the next value. (It shouldn't technically work for insertion, but it does).

`**********************
SkipList (size = 3)
Level: 2      (null),    ,    , (5)
Level: 1      (null), (3), (4), (5)
**********************`

Above, is what the Skip List looks like currently.

Below, is the structure of the Skip List I'm making. The Left-Hand sentinels are nodes with data that is null; we also have a phantom node acting as the head; the phantom head helps us keep track of the current number of levels in the Skip List. [Diagram of structure](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Skip_list.svg/500px-Skip_list.svg.png)

```
private Node<T> search(T key) {
    Node<T> node = head;
    boolean found = false;

    while (!found) {
        while (compare(node.getNext().getData(), key) <= 0) {
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        if (node.getDown() != null) {
            node = node.getDown();
        } else {
            node = node.getNext();
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

In its current state, if we try `search(4)`, the returned node will be `5`, even though `4` is in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing a number of problems here.

1. Where are you actually returning the value?  I see no return statement, though I presume you just left out a `return node;` at the bottom.
2. You're never verifying that the final value is indeed what you're looking for.  You need some way to indicate that a value wasn't found, I'm assuming?
3. You currently just decide that you found the node if you weren't able to go down.

I think you need to re-think the algorithm a bit.  Try this code:

```
private Node<T> search(T key) {
    Node<T> node = head;
    boolean found = false;

    while (!found) {
        //special case to return a node containing null - indicates value not in list
        if (node == null) return new Node(null);
        //We found it!
        else if (node.getData().equals(key)) found = true;
        //Go to the next one over if it's not too high.
        else if (node.getNext() != null && compare(node.getNext().getData(), key) <= 0) node = node.getNext();
        //It was too high, so go down instead.
        else node = node.getDown();
    }
    return node;
}
```

Note the checking for a null condition in the inner while loop - this prevents you from calling `getData()` on a non-existent next node, which would result in a null pointer exception.  Also note how you don't check for null values going down.  This is because you only encounter it if it's not in the list, so the special case at the start will catch that null value the next time the loop executes.

You can also tweak how it checks if the values are equal.  I used `.equals` but you can change it to use the `compare` method, depending on how you check for equality.

Comment: This works for just finding the element. I wanted to find the node if it was in this list--but if it wasn't, return the next highest value in the list; that way, I could easily insert the new value right before that returned node.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Have you tested that the `compare` method is called correctly?  I could see it being the problem if you meant to use `>=` rather than `<=`.

Comment: The method looks like this: `compare(T a, T b)`, then I do `a.compareTo(b)`. I know that if we ran `search(3)`, then it would get to a point where it compares `3.compareTo(5)`, which returns `-1` correctly; which is why I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure your method works either. If we `search(3)`, then we end up going to `5`, then down to `5`. This isn't correct. It should go down the left-hand column until the `data <= node.next.data`. Your algorithm immediately goes to the first `5` on level 2.